# Google maps 3D not working on VirtualBox

Tags: google-chrome, google-maps

Why `maps.google.com`'s 3D feature while running `Chrome` (latest) on `Ubuntu 18` in a virtual environment (`VirtualBox`) with `Windows 10` host is not enabled?

Virtual Machine's settings:

```
Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager | Settings | System:

Paravirtualization Interface: KVM
Hardware Virtualization: Enable Vt-x/AMD-V (checked)
                         Enable Nested Paging (checked)
```

The setting, 'Use hardware acceleration' is enabled in Chrome:

```
Settings | Advanced
Use hardware acceleration when available (checked)
```

Answer (score 0):

On VB 6.0.14 I had similar settings as you and needed to use

- VMSVGA
- **disable** (**uncheck**) Display > Acceleration: activate 3d acceleration

to get 3d Google maps on Fedora 30 Gnome guest in Chrome. Unfortunately I lost dual display support with this change, what made me return to VBoxSVGA without 3D Support (couldn't make it work).